# Error when checking package with Github Actions "Error: Unknown command: cask"

Tags: r, github, travis-ci, github-actions

I'm relatively new to building R packages and I just attempted to move from Travis CI to Github Actions.

When I try to run a check using GHA the job fails. It appears that the cask command is throwing things off, but I'm unsure how to fix it (see photo).

A couple of forum posts noted that the "cask" command is outdated, but I never wrote it into the workflow so I'm unsure where it's being called from.

Would greatly appreciate any tips!

[image: Error message in GHA]

Answer (score 1):

It seems the tutorial you used to install Cask is outdated.

`cask` is no longer a brew command.

When you want to install a Cask, just do `brew install` or `brew install --cask` **instead of** `brew cask install` (as shown in line 8 on your print).

Possibly, if you need to know how to do something with brew, you can always use brew help, or read the manual with man brew. `brew help <command>` will also show you a help message for a command (e.g. `brew help upgrade`).

[*Source*](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/902)